# How to add additional query parameters to a views page url?

Tags: views

I have a view with two displays as page. I need the URL of the pages as `gallery?display=grid` and `gallery?display=slideshow` and filter the views based on the additional parameter 'grid' or 'slideshow'.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Changing the style plugin (slideshow, map, list, table, etc) based in the display plugin (page, block, etc) is not supported as far as I know. You can always write a new display plugin and make changes to the global $view. I would rather go for views_embed_view call in my own hook_menu page callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load different displays by using the views_get_view_result() function.

```
$grid_view = views_get_view_result('YOURVIEWNAME', 'grid');
$grid = $grid_view[0];
```

More documentation is found [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7) and [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view/7)